# Why is there an RPG.SE Meta question listed as an upcoming event?

Tags: bug, meta

On the right hand column of RPG.SE, there's a link to a meta question ([Revisit III: Don’t Guess the System policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/revisit-iii-don-t-guess-the-system-policy)) with an "Upcoming events" header rather than the expected "Featured on Meta" as shown below:

[image: image of rpg.se with possible error]

Similarly on meta:

[image]

Is this a bug of some kind?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question in question has just reopened.

Comment: @Trish We don’t close questions on meta just because the thing they were asking about no longer applies. Otherwise we’d close every bug report with [meta-tag:status-completed], which we clearly do not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It was a hack

You'll find this covered in that question (and in the comments below), but to reiterate;

- We [decided](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/52137) that the Revisit should be locked for a week before allowing answers. The decision to "lock" was based on the assumption that the Wiki Answer lock only prevents answers, but on further investigation it also prevents votes and comments.
- So we decided to close it instead, which we thought only prevented answers, but it turns out it also prevents it being featured.
- As a hack around this limitation, I created a community event, which had the added boon of letting it show a time-down to when it would be reopened. Roughly.

The event has now expired and since the question is reopened it should show up as a normal Featured once that box caches (which is once per 24 hours, IIRC).

Answer (score 4):

Moderator Someone_Evil created the event so that the DGtS revisit would appear on the featured board while it was still a closed question.

[See this comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/revisit-iii-don-t-guess-the-system-policy#comment39799_11658)

[image]