# Should a question be put on hold because a moderator fears in advance that respondents will go off-topic?

Tags: discussion, moderation

[Is there an official streamlined/simplified version of the D20 system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97710/is-there-an-official-streamlined-simplified-version-of-the-d20-system) was actually answerable by a yes-or-no response with some backing evidence. The OP even grants that an acceptable answer ("no") was provided by a moderator in the comments.

Nonetheless, said moderator put the question on hold -- with no other votes -- as being a "shopping" question. Not because it's *actually* a shopping question, but due to fears that it would be *turned into* a shopping question by respondents. ("But that's not what our helpful members would answer with — they would say no, and then start compiling all kinds of 'but this 3rd party variant…' material...")

As a more general observation, the moderation on RPG.SE is completely out-of-line with any other forum on the SE network, being vastly more draconian than any other community in its application of the rules. Will this aggressive level of hyper-moderation continue to be the norm?

Comment: Related reading pursuant to your line "will this aggressive level of hyper-moderation continue to be the norm?" A long meta conversation in (at least) three parts: [1](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6080/23970), [2](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6090/23970), [3](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6129/23970).

Comment: I do think this might be better approached as two separate questions, though. (1) Is it appropriate to close this question in this way? (2) Will draconian moderation continue to be the norm?

Comment: Please pick one for us to talk about: re-opening a specific closed question, or challenging widespread moderation practices. There's no way to usefully address both at once; we've tried many times and it just turns into a muddy mess. You can make the other topic into another question if you feel that's necessary. "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once" applies to meta as well as to main site.

Comment: Yeah, this should be split into two questions — each will distract from the other. I'm going to be ironic and close this as too broad until it's one question. :)

Comment: @nvoigt "Don't answer (held questions) in comments" applies to meta too.

Comment: Since it doesn't seem like this question is going to get split, I'll go ahead and start a meta on the second part of the question, I'd like to get a community check-in anyway. https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6895/how-is-the-community-doing

Comment: The new linked question is not an accurate reflection this closed question.

Comment: @Daniel You're still free to edit this one. We'd vote to reopen it when it's workable.

Comment: If you won't use your words, then don't complain when someone else does.  And all you'd have to do to get this question reopened is remove the last paragraph so you're asking about one thing not two. I'm not sure why you're not taking that simple step if you actually do want input on your issue.

Comment: I'll be happy to add my vote to reopen if you edit as doppelgreener as requested, and as nitsua60 suggested.